# Angular js return to active tab?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I have two tabs in my page

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active pointer-cursor"><a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#home" ng-init="LCL='LCL'" ng-click="setCargoType(LCL)">Loose Cargo</a></li>
  <li class="pointer-cursor"><a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#menu1" ng-init="FCL='FCL'" ng-click="setCargoType(FCL)">Fixed Container</a></li>
</ul>

 <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  tab1
</div>

<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
  tab2
</div>
```

I have to stop tab switching after confirming any question.
like when user click on second tab and user clicks "cancel" , then it should returns on tab1.
If somebody can help me , thanks

Comment: Use [Angular-UI Tabs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tabs) instead of jQuery-ui-tabs. They are properly integrated with the AngularJS framework.

Comment: @georgeawg can we achieve this by using   jQuery-ui-tabs.?